# gmaps4rails V2 unable to retrieve markers position

Tags: google-maps, gmaps4rails, gmaps4rails2

I'm using gmaps4rails V2 and and I'm not able to retrieve the markers position.

I have my array of Markers:

```
markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
```

I want to iterate over it and delete the marker out of my map bounds

```
$.each markers, ->       
  pos = this.getPosition
  if !bounds.contains pos  
    handler.removeMarker this
```

This is my console output:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Marker> has no method 'getPosition'
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What does `handler.addMarkers()` do? It seems that `markers` are not markers at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Markers created by the gem are proxy on which you can create some methods.

To access the google object do:

```
 this.getServiceObject()
```

Then:

```
 this.getServiceObject().getPosition() // mind the parenthesis!
```